# inverse boolean result based on method argument

Tags: java

Could you please propose neat snippet of java code to inverse boolean result based on method argument.
Here is not working example:

```
public boolean isSomethingTrue(boolean inverseLogic) {
  boolean resultOfCalculation = ...
  return inverseLogic && resultOfCalculation;
}
```

---

```
result  | inverse  | desired return
true    | false     | true
false   | false     | false        
true    | true      | false
false   | true      | true
```

Comment: You're looking for XOR, which is true is the two arguments are different and false if they are the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the ternary operator :

```
public boolean isSomethingTrue(boolean inverseLogic) {
    boolean resultOfCalculation = ...
    return inverseLogic ? !resultOfCalculation : resultOfCalculation;
}
```

Another option is XOR :

```
public boolean isSomethingTrue(boolean inverseLogic) {
    boolean resultOfCalculation = ...
    return inverseLogic ^ resultOfCalculation;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks, that was silly question... In fact I had parameter 'straightLogic' and failed to make it work with xor operator

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the truth table that you want:

```
inverse?    calculation    return-value
 false       false          false
 false       true           true
 true        false          true
 true        true           false
```

then you may notice this is exactly the truth table for `inverseLogic XOR resultOfCalculation`.

However, this may be a slightly obscure operation so either comment it well so you understand it when you read back the code at a later time, or use the ternary `.. ? .. : ..` as suggested by Eran - it probably generates *slightly* more inefficient code but in all but the most critical systems you will prefer the readable version.